# Counting the total numbers of records in MySQL DB

Tags: mysql

I have to count the total numbers of records from my database. I want to know the efficient/faster way for MySQL to do this. I can use:

(1)

```
$rslt=mysql_query("select * from table");
$count = mysql_num_rows($rslt);
```

or (2) by using the following query:

```
select count(*) from table;
```

Which QUERY to the database is efficient?

Comment: Usually the best way to find out which query is fastest is to just run it and see.

Comment: FYI, this doesn't count the number of records in the DB, just in one table of the DB. You'll have to repeat it for every table to get the total for the DB.

Comment: i meant to say that @Barmar I want to count the rows in the table "table"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first (`select * from ...`) will have to actually read the rows, while the second will return an `int` from the database.  The second will be much faster with large tables.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is really large I would expect the 2nd query to outperform the first.

1. It does not need to actually fetch a ton of data from DB to client.  `SELECT *` is a horrible idea in such case.  `SELECT 1` would not have to load every field.
2. If your table is indexed on its primary key, RDBMS might be able to get the result excursively from index.